QGIS/Lizmap : Custom filter on inherited layer
I just started a new job and I get to work with Lizmap to create custom maps for each French region. To achieve this I would like to use the parent/child feature from Lizmap to create a parent project that contains every country scale layer. With a parent project I could create a project for each region with the specific regions layer combined to the inherited layers from the parent project. I tried this and it worked pretty well but I've got an issue with this architecture. I would like to have specific filter for each region on the inherited layers to only show the data for the given region but Lizmap only use the parent filter.
I tried multiple solutions but none of them worked :

I tried to create a project variable for each region use it in the parent filter. But it seems that I can't interpret a variable in the query builder. (I tried "code_dep IN (@liste_dep) where liste_dep is a variable that contains every departments for a given region)
I also tried to write a Python macro in QGIS. It worked pretty well in my local QGIS but doesn't execute at all in Lizmap. I used the "def openProject()" macro to apply my filter at the start.

I can still do it without using the parent/child feature but it would help me a lot to maintain the whole project.
